# Extremal bases in finite-dimensional Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convexity

**Definition.** A basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ for a Banach space $X$ is called *extremal* if there exists a point $s$ in the unit sphere $S_X=\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}$ such that for every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ the intersection $(s+\mathbb R\cdot e_i)\cap B_X$ of the line $s+\mathbb R\cdot e_i$ with the unit ball $B_X=\{x\in X:\|x\|\le 1\}$ is contained in the unit sphere $S_X$.

**Example 1.** The standard basis $e_1,e_2$ of the Banach space $\ell_\infty(2)$ is extremal. On the other hand, the basis $e_1+e_2,e_1-e_2$ is not extremal in $\ell_\infty(2)$.

**Example 2.** Every basis in a smooth finite-dimensional Banach space is not extremal (a Banach space is *smooth* if its unit ball has a unique support hyperplane at each points of the unit sphere).

> **Problem.** Has every finite-dimensional Banach space a non-extremal basis?

**Remark.** The answer to this problem is affirmative for 2-dimensional Banach spaces.

---

This problem was posed on 30 March 2021 by Taras Banakh on [page 64](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=3&page=64) of [Volume 3](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=3) of [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php).

**Prize.** A joint non-extremal bicycle ride near Lviv with beer and pizza included.