# Non-closed trajectories in convex billiards

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, convex-geometry, fixed-point-theorems

This is a weak version of [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/388960/61536), written down in [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php).

I start with necessary definitions.

Let $K=-K$ be a centrally symmetric compact convex body in the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$, and $\partial K$ be the boundary of $K$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

**Definition.** A 1-dimensional linear subspace $L\subset \mathbb R^n$ is called an *$K$-admissible direction* if for every $x\in\partial K$ the intersection $\partial K\cap(x+L)$ contains at most two points. It this case we can define the map $\theta_L:\partial K\to\partial K$ assigning to every point $x\in\partial L$ the unique point $\theta_L(x)$ such that $\partial K\cap(x+L)=\{x,\theta_L(x)\}$.

**Remark 1.** By the answer to [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/388564/61536), the set of $K$-admissible directions is dense in the space $Gr(1,\mathbb R^n)$ of all 1-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$.

> **Problem.** Are there $K$-admissible directions $L_1,\dots,L_m$ such that the map $$\theta_{L_m}\circ \dots\circ \theta_{L_1}:\partial K\to\partial K$$ has no fixed points?

**Remark 2.** For $n=2$ the answer to this problem is affirmative with $m=n=2$.

**Example.** For the convex body $K=[-1,1]^2$ in $\mathbb R^2$ and the special directions $L_1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x-y=0\}$ and $L_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x+y=0\}$, the map $\theta_{L_2}\circ\theta_{L_1}:\partial K\to\partial K$ has no fixed points.

Comment: Any comments on my question https://mathoverflow.net/q/391839/121665?

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz I made a comment, but not very valuable (probably it should be deleted). Concerning you question, I have never seen such result and it is not obvious (for $n>1$).